# Self reference exception after extending ResteasyJacksonProvider

Tags: java, rest, jackson, jax-rs, resteasy

We have jax.rs rest application build on Resteasy version 3.1.0.Beta2.

Via extending `Application` class we add our rest resources and also othre filtres and providers.

One of them is also `ResteasyJacksonProvider`

```
@ApplicationPath("")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    final private Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet<>();

    public ApplicationConfig() {
        this.resources.add(ResteasyJacksonProvider.class);

        this.resources.add(UserProfileResource.class);
        this.resources.add(StatsResource.class);

    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(this.resources);
    }
}
```

Everythings works fine till I extend it and replace with my custom provider.

```
@Provider
@Consumes({"application/*+json", "text/json"})
@Produces({"application/*+json", "text/json"})
public class SecureJacksonProvider extends ResteasyJacksonProvider {

}
```

But now I am getting strange exception for one of the rest calls:

Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain...

**So question is**: If there is some reference cycle why it works with default `ResteasyJacksonProvider` but not with its child.

*Note:
I have tried using also `JacksonJsonProvider` which is parent of `ResteasyJacksonProvider` and it also thows that exception. - It leads me to think if there can be some problem with dependencies but I found nothing.*